# Java Web Spring не инициализирует объекты, помеченные @Autowired

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, mvc, tomcat

********Есть java web приложение с использованием Spring Web MVC, при попытке деплоя в томкат выдает NoSuchBeanDefinitionException, хотя бин прописан в контексте спринга

Класс :

```
package com.freelance.web;

import com.freelance.model.Order;
import com.freelance.repository.OrderRepository;
import com.freelance.service.FreelanceService;
import com.freelance.service.FreelanceServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {
    **@Autowired
    private FreelanceService service;**

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getHomePage() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "neworder", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getOrderPage() {
        return "neworder";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "neworder", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postOrderPage(@RequestParam("amount") int amount, @RequestParam("phone") String phone) {
        Order order = new Order(amount, phone);
        return "neworder";
    }
}
```

**spring-config.xml**

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.freelance.repository.*" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.freelance.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.freelance.web"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>


    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="orderRepository" class="com.freelance.repository.jdbc.JdbcOrderRepository">
    </bean>
    <bean id="freelanceService" class="com.freelance.service.FreelanceServiceImpl" init-method="init">
    </bean>

    <bean class=     "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/webapp/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/> </bean>



</beans>
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 2):

Добавь на поле `private FreelanceService service;` аннотацию `@Qualifier("freelanceService")`